# In RSA, how would I choose e so it has nearly 400 digits?

Tags: cryptography, rsa

Yes this is admittedly for an assignment. I've already generated `phi(n)` using `p` and `q` using Miller-Rabin, and now I need to generate `e`. It's my understanding that it's standard to use 3 or 65537 as `e`, but I'm specifically supposed to "find e – a 398 digit number that is relatively prime with phi(n)"

My question is how? It seems like trying to find the factors of huge numbers is the very problem that makes RSA secure, and looping through every 400-digit number and testing for relative primality seems obviously wrong so I feel like I'm misunderstanding something.

Thanks for any help

---

Edit:

Code I'm currently working with

```
def generate_e(r):
    # r is phi(n)
    e = long_string()  # uses a string as a seed
    e = base_10(e)  # converts string to base-10
    e = e % pow(10, 398)  # make len(e) == 398

    # make e odd
    if e % 2 == 0:
        e -= 1

    # iterate over increasing odd numbers until relative prime with phi(n) is found
    while extended_euclid(e, r) != 1:
        e += 2

    return e
```

Comment: e is "relatively prime" to phi(n)  means that the GCD(e, phi(n)) = 1. The euclidean GCD algorithm doesn't need any factors and is very fast.

Comment: testing relatively prime is not hard. use GCD(e,phi(n))

Comment: And before you ask your next question, note that all the information and all the algorithms including psuedo-code that you'll likely need are in wikipedia, on the [RSA page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) and on the [page for the extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers)

Comment: Why do you need 398-bit e?

Comment: @JamesKPolk I think I'm understanding. I've added code that I've come up with, would you mind having a look?

Comment: @Grav that code should work fine.  Once you have e, then you need to compute d as the inverse of e mod phi(n).  Normally extended gcd gives you the value you need for d, but the way you coded it, it looks like you're only getting the gcd back.